# How to start a thread and instantly get back to the main code?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a simple view and a complicated function inside of it:

```py
def addWord(request):

    def calculate():
        <code>

    form = WordCreationForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        calculate()
        form.save()
        form = WordCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'add_word.html')
```

I need `calculate()` to run independently. I don't need any callbacks. I just want to start it, and then immediately get back to saving the form. So, I did this:

```py
import threading
def addWord(request):

    def calculate(num):
        <code>

    form = WordCreationForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        threading.Thread(target=calculate, args=(request.POST['num'],)).start()
        form.save()
        form = WordCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'add_word.html')
```

But in this case, form still won't be saved and rendered again untill `calculate()` is done.

So, what is the best way to start `calculate()` asynchronically?

Answer (score 0):

Your threading logic looks sound to me and the below example illustrates the same behaviour:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def printer(): 
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("printer")                                                                                                                                                                                          

 def main(): 
     Thread(target=printer).start() 
     print("finished") 

main()
```

It outputs:

```
finished
printer
```

How have you confirmed that `calculate` is not being called until after? Or that is succeeds (it could be hitting an exception without you noticing)

Comment: This might make sense as a comment, rather than as an answer.